# SQL Server: no search results caused by noise words

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, full-text-search

I've moved a database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2014 via an import/export through SQL Server 2008 to make it compatible to be imported in 2014. So far that has worked fine.

I found out that using words which are usually in a stop list (like articles) disrupts or breaks the retrieval in a FullText search and return no results. Using only the important keywords returns the result as usual. [AFAIK in older versions of SQL Server a different system than stop list were used.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1491/sql-server-full-text-search-noise-words-and-thesaurus-configurations/) Although I can not find anything relevant in the *FTData* folder because it is either empty or commented.

On inspecting the database via SQL Server Management Studio I see that no stop list is configured in the selected database (under *Storage*). I tried adding a new one based on the system stop list but it made no difference to the behavior.

What can cause this behavior?

**UPDATE**

The used query:

```
SELECT ProductID FROM SearchTable WHERE CONTAINS(*, '"word"') AND
CONTAINS(*, '"noiseword"')
```

The results fail because in the search query the words are connected with AND. Using a noise word apparently returns always false so no item is returned.

I tried to change that behavior but it is not prevented by this:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'transform noise words', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

I will try a rebuild which may help based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142490.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CREATE_FULLTEXT_INDEX_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) article, as suggested by wBob.

Comment: You might be better off dropping the existing full-text index and rebuilding from scratch in 2014 to see if you get a different behaviour.  You should also try running some tests with `sys.dm_fts_parser` eg something like this:  `SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser( '"test a n noise the word"', 1033, 0, 0 )`

Comment: I see that only English words are filtered, however the used language is German. Can I change that?

Comment: `LANGUAGE` is one of the arguments of the `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX` command.  I suggest you have a good read over [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CREATE_FULLTEXT_INDEX_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply deactivating the stop list fixed the problems. There may be better solutions but this worked for me.

```
Use database; 
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table
   SET STOPLIST OFF;
GO
```